# how to create a VirtualHost to serve only static content

Tags: apache, virtualhost, static-content

I want to create a virtual host in apache such that it serves only static content like stylesheets, videos, images, javascripts, text files, etc. I am not looking at any "processing" capabilities from this virtual host.

Comment: To extend the question, a good answer would include directives "to inform the browser to keep files in its own cache" and "to have be cookieless requests".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a `VirtualHost` entry as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.tld
    ServerName media.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/media"

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/media-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/media-access_log" common

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/media>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    SetHandler default-handler
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I removed the `ServerAdmin`, `ServerName` and all those lines pertaining to logs and then restarted apache. I observe it is serving php files

Comment: @deostroll: I updatd my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: it didn't work as expected. Do we still need the `Location` tag?

Comment: @deostroll: you can remove `Location`, `SetHandler` can be placed inside the `Directory` tag, too. Change its value to `default-handler`.