# Smartgwt images on tomcat

Tags: image, tomcat, war, smartgwt

Using smartgwt 2.4.0 i have created a war. Running on jetty everything works fine.
But once I deploy my war on tomcat, everything works fine except for my images; like the logo.

My smartgwt is mavenized, I dont know if this causes the problem. Anyways my path to my images is: src/main/webapp/images

So bassicly in my webapp I've created a directory images. When I check my war, this directory exists, altho tomcat seems to refuse to load my images.

In my java code I set a certain image like so (again on jetty it works fine, except for tomcat):

```
Img logo = new Img("/images/logo.png", 1000, 100);
```

Comment: are you talking about the embedded Jetty on eclipse ? Development mode ? Production mode ? Did you test multiple versions of tomcat ?

Comment: Yes I was talking about embedded eclipse. When deploying the application it was on apache-tomcat-7.0.22

Answer (score 2):

Use server-relative URLs to all external resources like images, stylesheets, script files, etc.

Server-relative URLs begin with the context path to the web application. If your web application is mapped to context path `/mywebapp` and your images are in the folder `images` at the root of the context path, the correct URL to `logo.png` would be:

```
/mywebapp/images/logo.png
```

Having said that, [use Apache to serve static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112577/how-to-create-a-virtualhost-to-serve-only-static-content), requiring Tomcat to serve only dynamic content.

Comment: Really bad advice.. mywebapp can change depending on the environment you are. You should use completely relative paths, like "images/logo.png".